# Is it a good idea minimise work for garbage collector by deleting

Tags: python, django, garbage-collection

Suppose we have a `APIView` like this which returns large queryset. Can I minimise the work for garbage collector by doing like this?

```
class MyView(APIView) 
  def get_list(self, request, format=None):
    params=request.query_params
    result = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(result, many=True)
    del result #deleting explicitly here
    del params #deleting explicitly here
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I read that calling `gc.collect()` in each request is not a good idea. Is this a good idea to do this so that garbage collector will have less stuff to collect garbage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your del statements won’t do anything, since the objects these variables referenced have other references pointing to them.

Second of all, even if this wasn’t the case, del statement removes a variable but don’t garbage collect the data it was referencing.

And finally, automatic garbage collection was designed to relieve the developer from having to explicitly deallocate memory. Peppering your code with garbage collection statements will a) stand in the way of optimal garbage collection algorithm, and b) will reduce code readability.

Having said all that, I’ve had performance troubleshooting situations where all signs were pointing at the garbage collector and it was tempting to add an explicit garbage collection statement. Usually though, even if this measure helps in the short term, the problem will come back at some point.

Modern solutions to garbage collection problem, at least in the area of microservices, include disabling garbage collection altogether and shutting down/restarting the process once it reaches a certain memory threshold.

Comment: **since the objects these variables referenced have other references pointing to them** why so why it is linked reference -> reference?

Comment: I’d like to add that If your Django API view is slow, there are lots of ways to optimize it before you should worry about garbage collector.